# Why can't we use interpolation expression with "ng-model" but can use with "ng-src"?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am trying to use the interpolation expression with the `ng-model` directive but it doesn't work. On the contrary, when I use interpolation with `ng-src`, it works perfectly fine. What is this difference due to?

Comment: Sometimes when you think you need interpolation in ng-model, you can get away with indexing syntax instead. ng-model="$scope[propertyName].subprop"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It all depends upon how the directive has been setup.

Some directives like `ng-model`, `ng-show` and `ng-click` do not use interpolation symbols whereas directives `ng-src` take interpolation.

Interpolation are supported on directives that work only with strings. If we look at ng-src implementation you will find

```
 attr.$observe(normalized, function(value) {
          if (!value)
             return;

          attr.$set(attrName, value);

          if (msie) element.prop(attrName, attr[attrName]);
        });
```

`attr.$observe` watches for change in attribute not model. Model changes cause attribute changes (due to interpolation), hence causing the trigger to fire.

For all other directives like `ng-model`, the attribute value is an expression which is evaluated in current scope and is not limited to string value.

If you are developing your own directives, isolated scope properties `=` and `@` help you achieve something similar.

Answer (score 0):

It's to do with when the code in the directive looks at the attribute: before or after interpolation.

I suspect `ngModel` uses the attribute, and by that I mean passing it to `$parse` or `$eval`, as it is **before** interpolation.

However, the directive `ngSrc` uses the attribute, and by that I mean setting the `src` attribute or not to the attribute value, **after** interpolation.

The reason as to why `ngModel` uses the value before interpolation, but `ngSrc` uses it after, I suspect is to do with how they're coded up. Consider the directive

```
<my-directive my-attr="{{ 'name' }}"></my-directive>
```

coded up as:

```
app.directive('myDirective', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    link: function($scope, $element, $attrs) {
      console.log('Link:', $attrs.myAttr);       // Outputs "name"
    },
    controller: function($scope, $element, $attrs) {
      console.log('Controller:', $attrs.myAttr); // Outputs "{{ 'name' }}"
    }
  };
});
```

The un-interpolated value is seen in the controller, but the post-interpolated value is seen in the linking function. So the order of the (relevant) events is

- controller,
- then interpolation,
- then linking function.

You can [see this example in a Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/4xlBSvTDJedBePVn2vy0?p=preview). I suspect `ngModel` uses the value from the controller, and therefore sees the pre-interpolated value, but `ngSrc` uses the linking function, and so sees the post-interpolated value.

One reason as to why `ngModel` uses the controller rather than the linking function, I suspect is so that it can expose the controller to other directives, which can use it via their `require` option.

---

A slightly confounding complication is that `ngSrc` doesn't expect the attribute to be a valid Angular expression. Rather than passing it through `$parse` or `$eval`, it just uses the post-interpolated value of the attribute directly. (i.e. it doesn't need the URL to be wrapped in quotes).

If you wanted to, you could write a directive that combines interpolation with Angular expressions. From the linking function you can pass the attribute to `$parse` or `$eval`. If the post-interpolated value is a valid Angular expression, this would work. You could do the same thing from the controller, but you would have to pass the value through `$interpolate` first.

As you have discovered, `ngModel` does't support this. However, I don't see why you couldn't write some basic version of `ngModel` that supports both, and so could be used as

```
my-model="myScope{{ 'VariableName' }}"
```

that accesses the scope variable `myScopeVariableName`.

To bring it back tot the question again, why `ngModel` itself doesn't support this, I suspect is because use cases are limited (the OP didn't mention one in the question), and so would add complexity to the directive without good reason.

Answer (score -2):

It has to do with one way vs two way data binding provided by directives isolated scope. Check out "Isolated Scope Explained" section in the follwoing post:

http://www.undefinednull.com/2014/02/11/mastering-the-scope-of-a-directive-in-angularjs/

Comment: When answering a question you should elaborate as much as possible, and not just post a link.