# Re-use template with different data models

Tags: angularjs, angular-ngmodel, angular-directive

I am using Angular 1.4.7 to create a form with multiple text fields. The form is used to

- (a) enter new data or
- (b) display existing data (read-only).

**Different data models are used to enter and display data.**

The form is divided into small sub-templates using `app.directive()`:

```
app.directive('usedProducts', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        templateUrl: 'used-products.html',
        scope: {
            readOnlyMode: '@'
        }
    };
});
```

Use form to enter data:

```
<used-products></used-products>
```

Use form to display data (read-only):

```
<used-products readOnlyMode="true"></used-products>
```

The code of my sub-template (`used-products.html`):

```
<div class="col-md-12">
  <textarea auto-height
    type="text" class="form-control"
    id="fooBar"
    ng-init="isReadOnly = (readOnlyMode.toLowerCase() === 'true' || false)"
    ng-model="isReadOnly ? my.readOnly.model.foo : my.other.enterData.model.fooBar"
    ng-readonly="isReadOnly"
    ng-attr-rows="isReadOnly ? '5' : '10'">{{readOnlyMode}}, {{isReadOnly}}</textarea>
</div>
```

The code above is **not working**, so rather see it as my expectation. Basically, I want to switch between two values for `ng-model` based on a parameter that I pass to the sub-template. I also want to set the textarea to `readonly` based on the value. The `rows` was included for debug purposed only.

How can I make my code working or what better way is there, to re-use a template with different data models? I'm new to AngularJS and this was the only idea I could come up with, so far.

**// Edit:** Re-using a template with different models did not work out for me, so eventually I ended up duplicating my code to have two different templates with individual models referenced in each.

Comment: Best is to use one template for read-only and another which is read-write. So you can just `ng-if` or `ng-switch` between them depending whether is read-only or not or depending on which conditions you might have. `ng-model="{{ ... }}"` (interpolation) will not work. Check also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30273309/why-cant-we-use-interpolation-expression-with-ng-model-but-can-use-with-ng-s).

Comment: if you need dynamic forms, then you might want to take a look at [angular-formly](http://angular-formly.com/#/).

Comment: Also instead of `readOnly: { readOnly: '@readOnly' }` I think you want `scope: { readOnly: '@readOnly' }`. Note that `@` means that your expression will be evaluate as a string. In Angular 1.5 you would do `scope: { readOnly: '<readOnly' }`, but you are not there.

Comment: @andreim: I do not want to maintain two forms that are entirely the same, except for the read-only state. That is why I was looking for a way to reuse a single template.

Comment: @andreim: Sorry, missing out the ``scope`` was a typo. I fixed my question. I use ``scope`` in my actual code, but it does not work as expected.

Comment: yes, as said in the 1st comment, you can simply do `<textarea ng-if="readOnly == 'true'" ng-model="my.readOnly.model.foo">` and `<textarea ng-if="!readOnly'" ng-model="my.other.enterData.model.fooBar">`. Don't bother with any other complex thinking, this works and you might need to customize separate templates in the future.

Comment: @andreim: But that way I would double each textarea within a *single* template, which is even worse in terms of maintainability.

Comment: what happens if the next day the designer comes and tells that he doesn't need the textarea when displayed in read-only mode :) he just want to be cooler than a textarea

Answer (score 0):

use `scope` to bind attributes to the directive

```
app.directive('usedProducts', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        templateUrl: 'used-products.html',
        scope: {
            readOnly: '@readOnly'
        }
    };
});
```

since `ng-model` is angular directive don't use any curly brackets. also avoid writing expressions inside `ng-model`.alternatively you can use `ng-init`

```
<div class="col-md-12">
  <textarea auto-height
    type="text" class="form-control"
    id="fooBar"
    ng-init="my.model = (readOnly.toLowerCase() == 'true') ? my.readOnly.model.foo : my.other.enterData.model.fooBar"
    ng-model="my.model"
    ng-readonly="readOnly.toLowerCase() == 'true'"
    rows="{{ readOnly.toLowerCase() == 'true' ? 5 : 10 }}></textarea>
</div>
```

Comment: I removed the curly brackets and used ng-init, but I still does not work. Seems like readOnly is not even set in the sub-template. Any idea what I still might be doing wrong?

Comment: I have updated my question with the new knowledge, but it still won't work. The variable ``readOnlyMode`` is not set in the sub-template at all. I.e. no value is printed, when I echo ``{{readOnlyMode}}``, not even ``undefined``.